# How to select data between two dates using 'AND','OR' clause?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i am trying to fetch data from database table in between two dates and it is having two more filter using 'OR' clause but in result i am getting data either between date or data fetched using 'OR' clause.I am posting here query in model if anyone knows solution please let me know.
Thanks in advance

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Transaction');
$this->db->join('Users', 'Transaction.user_id = Users.id');
$this->db->where('date >=',$startDate);
$this->db->where('date <=',$endDate);
$this->db->where( 'against = Recharge');
$this->db->or_where('against =','Rech_Commission');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I want date filter compulsory but want to fetch records against=Recharge or against='Rech_commission'but i am getting either using date range or against='Rech_Commission'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$where = '(against="Recharge" or against = "Rech_Commission")';
$this->db->where($where);
```

and you had date and date and (against = '' or against = '')

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('Transaction');
    $this->db->join('Users', 'Transaction.user_id = Users.id');
    $this->db->where('date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate)).'"');
    $this->db->where('against="Recharge" OR against = "Rech_Commission")';
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Transaction');
$this->db->join('Users', 'Transaction.user_id = Users.id');
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where('date >=',$startDate);
$this->db->where('date <=',$endDate);
$this->db->where( 'against = Recharge');
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->or_where('against =','Rech_Commission');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```